# Jquery mobile - Weird behaviour of href

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, href

I am using jquery (jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min), jquery mobile (jquery.mobile-1.1.0) and phoneGap.

In queryWLSuccess, Every link  has unique ID according to the database and click each link will display details of the link when I transfer the name which contain the ID. things work fine when I didn't use href='#' (display each link ID ='1', ID='2',...correctly) but after added the href='#'(display each link ID ='2', ID='2',ID='2',... same ID to all links)

What is happening for this weird behaviour? How to navigate to other external page? I need to navigate to another page when click.

JS FILE

```
---DATABASE---
function queryWLDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM WORD WHERE Level='"+ sessionStorage.StudyLevel +"'ORDER BY Word_ID" , [], queryWLSuccess, errorCB);

    }

     function queryWLSuccess(tx, results) {

        var len = results.rows.length

        for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            $("<li class='content'><a  ***href='#'*** name='"+results.rows.item(i).ID+"'>"+results.rows.item(i).Eng+"</a></li>").appendTo(".wordList");
        }           
    }

---JQUERY MOBILE---
$( document ).delegate("#list", "pageshow", function() {
   $('.content').remove();
   onDeviceReady();
   db.transaction(queryWLDB, errorCB);
}); 

$("li.content a").live('click', function(){
    alert("ID =  "+$(this).attr("name")); 

});
```

INDEX.HTML WORDLIST PAGE

```
<div data-role="page" id="wordList">

<div data-role="content">   
    <ol class="list">

    </ol>

</div>

</div><!-- WordList page -->
```

Comment: If you check the jQuery mobile docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html you can see that `href="#"` will actually return false, so it is probably overriding your actions

Comment: If you need to navigate to another page, you just put the page url in the href e.g. `href="myOtherPage.html"`

Comment: Do you have `rel="external"` in your a tag?  http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html

Comment: I had put href='anotherPage.html' rel='external' before but have the weird behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved when I use

```
$.mobile.changePage("anotherpage.html", {transition: "slide"});
```

when for click listener.